# Why do bitbake recipes have do_configure[noexec] and do_compile[noexec] set to true?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

In almost every bitbake recipe I have seen, `do_configure[noexec] = "1"` and `do_compile[noexec] = "1"` is set (before do_install).

Why would the authors not want their own recipes to be compiled and configured? Am I missing some knowledge on Yocto and OpenEmbedded build system? Thanks. When I run `bitbake recipe_name` I do see it being compiled and working as usual.

Comment: Do you have an example of when this is used even though bitbaking the recipe would end up compiling something? Usually noexec is useful if you e.g. just ship a few configuration files or something else not needing any configure/compile steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick survey of most recipes in OpenEmbedded-Core shows the large majority don't set these variables. They are set in some recipes, usually where the configuration and compilation steps are not required, for example for a recipe just packaging configuration files or a packagegroups recipes which is just about dependencies.